# Rails authenticate_by with encrypted email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model with an encrypted email address

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :email
end
```

When disabling encryption and after creating a new user, I can run `User.authenticate_by(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])` to authenticate the user.

However, when enabling email encryption and registering a user, the `authenticate_by` method returns `nil`.

I can see this in the console:

```
irb(main):001> User.authenticate_by(email: "some.email@test.com", password: "some_password")
User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "{\"p\":\"vAcGA4sdf3rwesdfhHM6dfdsfdfdhuH+g==\",\"h\":{\"iv\":\"sdfs24434+ubm2y\",\"at\":\"9CfwefsefYT66SOwsdfsdf==\"}}"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

How can I run the `User.authenticate_by` method with an encrypted email address?

Comment: Are you *sure* the user exists and the email and password are correct? Does `User.find_by(email: "some.email@test.com")` work?

Comment: Is it possible the email was stored with different casing? `SOME.EMAIL@TEST.COM`?

Comment: Spelling and cases are correct but this returns nil: `User.find_by(email:User.last.email)`. `User.last.email` returns the correct email address.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that I used the out of box [non-deterministic approach to encryption](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#deterministic-and-non-deterministic-encryption) which is more secure but makes it impossible to query the database. With non-deterministic encryption you cannot retrieve a record for example using:

```
User.find_by(email: "some.email@test.com")
=> nil
```

Instead, I had to change to a less secure deterministic approach

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :email, deterministic: true
end
```

With this, the `authenticate_by` works, too.

Comment: and remember to set config.active_record.encryption.extend_queries = true in your environment file.